# C# Visual Studio Copy and Paste Combo Boxes alter eachother

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, combobox

When I copy and paste a combo box into the same form it seems to be linked to the source combo box. When I run the form and change one combo box the other changes as the same time. How do I remove the link between them so that when I change my comboBox3 it doesnt call comboBox31 also?

So that:

`comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

wont call the

`comboBox31_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`  function?

Each of the combo Boxes are on different tabs in the form but they have the same values when I change either one. Both are connected to a database to get the values for the drop down.

Comment: can you paste some code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Because it is called when the value of selectedIndex changes it will call both because they are connected to the same data source and when one selection changes it calls the other. I have just edited my code to use a new connection string.